# android app google chat

Tags: google-talk

My girlfriend and I have been enjoying google chat and the feature that lets you know when the other person is on their phone indicated by a green circle vs a red circle when the phone is in sleep mode.
For some unexplained reason, my phone now indicats her status as being red all the time even when we are talking to  each other.
Shey says she has not changed any settings, 
can anyone tell me how to fix this or what woudl cause this to happen?

Comment: You must check on the status (work, busy, available) on both OS'.

Comment: Even a mistake with making a calender event could cause this. Just tell her to check her status.